# PowerShell XAML iOS style On/Off Button

Tags: powershell, xaml

As the name suggests, I'm trying to create an on/off type button using XAML and PowerShell, but cannot for the life of me find any guides or code on the internet.

I found a page with a great demo. Link [here](https://it-delinquent.medium.com/building-an-ios-style-toggle-button-in-wpf-and-xaml-678939f7e7ef).
This is how the code begins.

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
<Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
            <Viewbox>
                <Border x:Name="Border" CornerRadius="10"
```

When using XAML for PowerShell we can't utilise x: at all.

Here's another more indepth answer right here on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/865767/slider-on-off-switch-in-wpf). Same issue. There doesn't seem to be any resources for doing this without the dreaded x:

Anyone any ideas?

Comment: What schemas do you import?, See: [How to properly import XAML code to Powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56140555/1701026)

Comment: @iRon Easy as that eh? I was using Presentation only.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

U need to copy the style under here:

```
<Window.Resources>
<Style Key=“MyToggleStyle“ TargetType="ToggleButton">
```

Then u can use it on your button like this:

```
<ToggleButton Style="{StaticResource MyToggleStyle}" />
```

U can simply drop the x:
Name="Border"
TargetType="ToggleButton"